# Exchange accidentally forwards sent mails from one User to another User's Inbox

Tags: windows, email, exchange, users

Like the Topic says:

Our Exchange Server accidentally forwards sent mails from one User to another User's Inbox.

The sent mails are mostly to Outbound Adresses and they where successfully delivered but all those sent Mails are accidentally forwarded into our Info Mail account.

There are no Outlook rules defined and the forward routing in exchange is not used, for such things.

I really don´t know the cause of the problem and i don´t know where I have to look, because I´m new to exchange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the info mailbox is shared by multiple users and/or is added to another user's profile. What most likely happened is that the user sent those emails as the info account, in which case they ended up in the correct sent folder.

Comment: No thats not the case, the Mail appears in the sent Folder of the User, who has sent the mail. The Problem is, that the sent Email is getting forwarded into the Info Mailbox/ Inbox of that Info Account, without being Adressed to it...

Comment: That sounds like a rule in action. Check the Outlook rules for the user who sent the message.

Comment: Yap, it was a very old Rule, that we´ve forgotten... Thanks for the help!